# Unable to filter out falsey items from array

Tags: typescript

I have the following code which maps React children to a typed array:

```
const mappedChildren = React.Children.map(children, child => {
  if (child instanceof TableColumn) {
    return child as TableColumn;
  }
  return;
});
```

`mappedChildren` is of type `(TableColumn | undefined)[]`.  I now want to filter out the undefined values.  I'm using the following:

```
const columns: TableColumn[] = mappedChildren.filter(child => !!child);
```

I get the following error:

> Type '(TableColumn | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type
>   'O3TableColumn[]'. Type 'TableColumn | undefined' is not assignable to
>   type 'TableColumn'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type
>   'TableColumn'.

Comment: Use filter() to filter, not map(). If you want to map the filtered values, then use map() on the result of filter().

Comment: @JBNizet Reread the post...

Comment: I already have. My comment still applies.

Comment: @JBNizet smh.  On which line of code am I using filter to map?  I'm first mapping the items, then filtering.

Comment: Which is precisely the problem. You should filter, then map. Hence my comment saying "Use filter() to filter, not map(). If you want to map the filtered values, then use map() on the result of filter()".

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in comments, you shouldn't need to `map` twice.

Instead use `filter` to get only the items you care about and forget about handling `undefined` in your code.

```
const columns: TableColumn[] = React.Children.toArray(children).filter(child => {
  return child instanceof TableColumn;
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `React.Children.toArray(children).filter(child => child instanceof TableColumn)`?

Comment: AFAIK [there's no `React.Children.filter()`](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2956) but otherwise (with `toArray()`) this answer is correct!

Comment: Updated based on comments and this comment https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2956#issuecomment-215508632

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are happy to lose all *falsey* items, you can use:

```
const columns: TableColumn[] = <TableColumn[]>mappedChildren.filter(child => !!child);
```

Simplified example... If you do this in one hit, using `filter` as others have suggested in comments, you may still need a type assertion if you have strict null checks enabled:

```
const arr: (string | null)[] = [];
arr.push('string');
arr.push(null);
arr.push('string');

console.log(arr);
const filtered: string[] = <string[]>arr.filter((item) => { return typeof item === 'string'; });
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score -1):

Ultimately, I was able to accomplish what I needed by explicitly defining the `children` property of my component in the interface it extends:

```
export interface TableProps {
  children: React.ReactElement<TableColumnProps>[];
}
```